# Is $r(T)=r(S^{-1}TS)\;$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $E$ a complex Hilbert space and $L(E)$ the algebra of all bounded operators on $E$.
An operator $S\in L(E)$ is called positive if $\langle Sx, x\rangle\geq0$ for all $x\in E$, and we  write $S\geq 0$.

Recall that the spectral radius of an operator $T\in L(E)$ is given by
$$r(T)=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\|T^n\|^{\frac{1}{n}}.$$

> Let $S\geq 0$ be an invertible operator and $T\in L(E)$. Is
> $$r(T)=r(S^{-1}TS)\;??$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true, irrespective of $S$ being positive. You have
$$
S^{-1}TS-\lambda I=S^{-1}(T-\lambda I)S,
$$
which shows that $\sigma(S^{-1}TS)=\sigma(T).$ In particular, $$r(S^{-1}TS)=r(T).$$